# Setting post-build event commands?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, multi-device-hybrid-apps

Is it possible to set a post-build in VS2013 and Multi-Device Hybrid Apps CTP3?  I want to be able to copy the output APK to a different location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use MSBuild Post build event to copy the apk from bin\Android\Debug to your custom location. You can add PostBuildEvent to project file to execute the copy command or can run task to copy apk from one location to another.

```
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>   
    <PostBuildEvent>
   <Command>copy source_apk_location target_apk_location</Command>
      <Message>Making a copy of apk</Message>
    </PostBuildEvent>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

To edit the project file go to solution explorer, under project node contextmenu click Unload Project --> Edit *.jsproj and after making the changes reload the project.
[image]
[image]