# PreBuildEvent and PostBuildEvent on Visual Studio 2015 Tools for Apache Cordova

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova, post-build-event, pre-build-event

Does somebody know if there is a way to use PreBuildEvent and PostBuildEvent on the new Visual Studio 2015 Tools for Apache Cordova?

I tried this post, but it didn't work: [Setting post-build event commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27016704/setting-post-build-event-commands)

Answer (score 3):

I faced similar issue and i needed to delete a folder on build in my Cordova app build with VS 2015 . 
I found a solution in this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/10605248/581157 Hope this helps.

To delete a folder on Biuld of the cordova app i added this to the jsproj file

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Exec Command="CD  $(ProjectDir) 
RMDIR /S /Q platforms"/>
  </Target>
```